# Scrollable context menu in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have class for context menu, which inherits "ContextMenu" class from ComponentArt.

Complete hierarchy is:

```
ChartContextMenu
  ComponentArt.ExtendedContextMenu
    ComponentArt.ContextMenu
      ComponentArt.Menu
        ItemsControl
```

This menu hasn't its own XAML, just code and attached to XAMLs as:

```
<context:ChartContextMenu x:Name="contextMenu" Theme="{StaticResource Windows7Theme}" />.
```

**Problem: I would like to make this menu scrollable.**

I know how to make menu scrollable in case it has XAML (just envelop to the ScrollableView). But how to do it without XAML?

Comment: What about your own wrapper, wich simply add scrollview around control?

Comment: I cannot find any samples/docs how to do it in code only. Most of resources recommends to wrap menu in scrollableview in xaml, but say nothing about case similar to my.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like workaround. U shouldnt create controls in code only. Its bad practice!
Try to mix xaml/code. I`m sure it solve any problem.
p.s.
Also you cannot programatically create template for your control, but you can load it from a XAML string in code like this:

```
public static DataTemplate Create(Type type)
{
    return (DataTemplate) XamlReader.Load(
        @"<DataTemplate
            xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"">
            <" + type.Name + @"/>
          </DataTemplate>"
      );
}
```